# Angularjs component without module definition, components interaction

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-material

I'm a newbie to angularjs, trying to add some functionality to angularjs codebase
(angularjs 1.5 with angularjs material)

I don't see any module definitions `angular.module` in the components.
All components js files start with `class nameController` and end with an export `export const namrComponent`.
What is the proper way of adding a component in such a case?
I mean how do you tweak an example like [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) to fit in the codebase.

I tried creating a component under `app` folder and adding it to `index.module.js` but it doesn't seem to work.
I get errors saying `The controller with the name 'nameOfMyComponent' is not registered`

I'm also trying to put `md-switch` in one component (FirstComponent), and when its `ng-change` is fired I want another component (SecondComponent) to create `md-dialog` with md-list in it.
(SecondComponent) dialog will show a list of items with checkboxes, on hitting a submit button it will send the selected items to api; and return a success message to the (FirstComponent) to update the md-switch.
Is this flow possible? I mean the communication between components?
How to call one component from the other?